# replace a char with null after 5-th match

Tags: php

**Which is the best way to do the following ?**

```
# if I have the following string :
$str = "Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar";
# and I want to remove "o" character after 5-th match so result I need is :
$newStr = "Foo Bar Foo Bar Fo Bar F Bar F Bar F Bar F Bar...";
```

The way I know :

```
  $str = "Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar";
  $str = explode("o", $str);
  $new = "";
  $c = 1;
  foreach($str as $k) {
    if($c>5)
      $new .= $k;
    else 
      $new .= $k."o";
    $c++;
  }
```

*I believe there is a better way of doing this.*

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Are you asking for "give me teh codez"?

Comment: You're not a new user here.  You ought to be familiar with what would increase the chances of getting a reply / answer

Comment: No need to apologize, just wanted to point out that. Btw, shouldn't you `explode('', $str)` instead of `explode('0', $str)` ?

Comment: @asprin if my string will have 40 000 characters in my oppinion it will be better to have an array of characters between char I need to remove instead of having an array with 40K elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a million ways to do this. I had a quick scan through the built-in functions to see if there was a `strpos` with an n<sup>th</sup> occurance, but there was not.

Here is **a** solution. It might not be the best, but who knows.

```
$str = "Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar";

for (
    $offset = 0, $count = 0;
    $count < 5;
    $offset = strpos($str, 'o', $offset) + 1, $count++
);

$newStr = substr($str, 0, $offset++) .
    str_replace('o', '', substr($str, $offset));
```

Sorry for the mad for loop, been doing too much code golf lately!

Here's another way to do it.

```
$str = "Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo Bar";

$newStr = implode('o', str_replace('o', '',  explode('o', $str, 6)));
```

Comment: Looks nice, thanks for the answer